# Enlazado de multiples archivos

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, ld

Estaba haciendo pruebas con un par de archivos que estan planeados para ser un intento de `script` que pueda ser iniciado en un `bootloader`.
En principio hacia link entre los 2 archivos que componian el ejecutable (`kernel.c` y `loader.asm`) con este comando despues de haber compilado ambos.

```
ld -m elf_i386 -T linker.ld -o kernel kasm.o kc.o
```

Siendo `kc.o` el archivo `kernel.c` compilado y `kasm.o` el archivo `loader.asm` compilado, ambos compilados siguiendo los siguientes comandos:

```
gcc -m32 -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kc.o 

nasm -f elf32 loader.asm -o kasm.o
```

Luego decidí añadir un archivo de soporte a la combinación, añadiendo `kernelutils.c` como archivo de soporte para `kernel.c`. **¿Cómo debería plantear el linking para consegir el ejecutable? ¿Cómo debería proceder?**

**`kernel.c`**

```
/*
 *
 * kernel.c - version 0.0.1
 * This script is under the license of the distributed package, this license
 * can be found in the package itself
 * Script coded by Cristian Simón for the CKA Proyect
 * ----
 * License: GNU GPL v3
 * Coder: Cristian Simón
 * Proyect: CKA 
 * 
 */
/* Output defines */
#define BLACK_BGROUND 0X07 /* black background */
#define WHITE_TXT 0x07 /* light gray on black text */
#define GREEN_TXT 0x02 /* light green on black text */
#define RED_TXT 0x04 /* light red on black text*/
#define CYAN_TXT 0x03 /*light cyan on black text */

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cpuid.h>


void k_main() 
{
    k_clear_screen();
    k_printf(" Wellcome to", 0, WHITE_TXT);
    k_printf(" CKA!", 1, GREEN_TXT);
    k_printf("==============>", 2, WHITE_TXT);
    k_printf(" CKA stands for C Kernel with Assembly", 3, WHITE_TXT);
    k_printf(" Version 0.0.1, => based in the job of Debashis Barman", 4, WHITE_TXT);
    k_printf(" Contact => assemblyislaw@gmail.com / blueshell@mail2tor.com", 5, WHITE_TXT);
    k_printf("           or in the github repository page", 6, WHITE_TXT);
    k_sleep_3sec();
    k_clear_screen();
    /* here start the magic */
    k_printf(" !===> Starting Checkup <===!", 0, WHITE_TXT);
    k_printf(" =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-", 1, WHITE_TXT);

    k_printf("[KernelInfo] Switched to protected mode successfully", 5, CYAN_TXT);

}
```

**`kernelutils.c`**

```
/*
 *
 * kernel_util.c
 * This script is under the license of the distributed package, this license
 * can be found in the package itself
 * Script coded by Cristian Simón for the CKA Proyect
 * ----
 * License: GNU GPL v3
 * Coder: Cristian Simón
 * Proyect: CKA 
 * 
 */
#define BLACK_BGROUND 0X07 /* black background */
#define WHITE_TXT 0x07 /* light gray on black text */
#define GREEN_TXT 0x02 /* light green on black text */
#define RED_TXT 0x04 /* light red on black text*/
#define CYAN_TXT 0x03 /*light cyan on black text */

void k_clear_screen();
void k_sleep_3sec();
unsigned int k_printf(char *message, unsigned int line, float color);

/* k_clear_screen : to clear the entire text screen */
void k_clear_screen()
{
    char *vidmem = (char *) 0xC00B8000;
    unsigned int i=0;
    while(i < (80*25*2))
    {
        vidmem[i]=' ';
        i++;
        vidmem[i]=BLACK_BGROUND;
        i++;
    };
}

/* k_printf : the message and the line # */
unsigned int k_printf(char *message, unsigned int line, float color)
{
    char *vidmem = (char *) 0xC00B8000;
    unsigned int i=0;

    i=(line*80*2);

    while(*message!=0)
    {
        if(*message=='\n') /* check for a new line */
        {
            line++;
            i=(line*80*2);
            *message++;
        } else {
            vidmem[i]=*message;
            *message++;
            i++;
            vidmem[i]=color;
            i++;
        };
    };

    return(1);
}

/* 
* k_sleep_3sec : to make a simple delay of aprox 3 sec, since is a nasty sleep, 
* duration will vary
* from system to system
*/
void k_sleep_3sec()
{
    int c = 1, d = 1;
    for ( c = 1 ; c <= 20000 ; c++ )
    for ( d = 1 ; d <= 20000 ; d++ )
    {}
}
```

**`linker.ld`** (el script que uso para ld)

```
ENTRY(loader)
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)

SECTIONS {
   /* The kernel will live at 3GB + 1MB in the virtual
      address space, which will be mapped to 1MB in the
      physical address space. */
   . = 0xC0100000;

   .text : AT(ADDR(.text) - 0xC0000000) {
       *(.text)
       *(.rodata*)
   }

   .data ALIGN (0x1000) : AT(ADDR(.data) - 0xC0000000) {
       *(.data)
   }

   .bss : AT(ADDR(.bss) - 0xC0000000) {
       _sbss = .;
       *(COMMON)
       *(.bss)
       _ebss = .;
   }
}
```

**`loader.asm`**

```
global _loader                          ; Make entry point visible to linker.
extern k_main                           ; _main is defined elsewhere

; setting up the Multiboot header - see GRUB docs for details
MODULEALIGN equ  1<<0             ; align loaded modules on page boundaries
MEMINFO     equ  1<<1             ; provide memory map
FLAGS       equ  MODULEALIGN | MEMINFO  ; this is the Multiboot 'flag' field
MAGIC       equ    0x1BADB002     ; 'magic number' lets bootloader find the header
CHECKSUM    equ -(MAGIC + FLAGS)  ; checksum required

; This is the virtual base address of kernel space. It must be used to convert virtual
; addresses into physical addresses until paging is enabled. Note that this is not
; the virtual address where the kernel image itself is loaded -- just the amount that must
; be subtracted from a virtual address to get a physical address.
KERNEL_VIRTUAL_BASE equ 0xC0000000                  ; 3GB
KERNEL_PAGE_NUMBER equ (KERNEL_VIRTUAL_BASE >> 22)  ; Page directory index of kernel's 4MB PTE.


section .data
align 0x1000
BootPageDirectory:
    ; This page directory entry identity-maps the first 4MB of the 32-bit physical address space.
    ; All bits are clear except the following:
    ; bit 7: PS The kernel page is 4MB.
    ; bit 1: RW The kernel page is read/write.
    ; bit 0: P  The kernel page is present.
    ; This entry must be here -- otherwise the kernel will crash immediately after paging is
    ; enabled because it can't fetch the next instruction! It's ok to unmap this page later.
    dd 0x00000083
    times (KERNEL_PAGE_NUMBER - 1) dd 0                 ; Pages before kernel space.
    ; This page directory entry defines a 4MB page containing the kernel.
    dd 0x00000083
    times (1024 - KERNEL_PAGE_NUMBER - 1) dd 0  ; Pages after the kernel image.


section .text
align 4
MultiBootHeader:
    dd MAGIC
    dd FLAGS
    dd CHECKSUM

; reserve initial kernel stack space -- that's 16k.
STACKSIZE equ 0x4000

; setting up entry point for linker
loader equ (_loader - 0xC0000000)
global loader

_loader:
    ; NOTE: Until paging is set up, the code must be position-independent and use physical
    ; addresses, not virtual ones!
    mov ecx, (BootPageDirectory - KERNEL_VIRTUAL_BASE)
    mov cr3, ecx                                        ; Load Page Directory Base Register.

    mov ecx, cr4
    or ecx, 0x00000010                          ; Set PSE bit in CR4 to enable 4MB pages.
    mov cr4, ecx

    mov ecx, cr0
    or ecx, 0x80000000                          ; Set PG bit in CR0 to enable paging.
    mov cr0, ecx

    ; Start fetching instructions in kernel space.
    ; Since eip at this point holds the physical address of this command (approximately 0x00100000)
    ; we need to do a long jump to the correct virtual address of StartInHigherHalf which is
    ; approximately 0xC0100000.
    lea ecx, [StartInHigherHalf]
    jmp ecx                                                     ; NOTE: Must be absolute jump!

StartInHigherHalf:
    ; Unmap the identity-mapped first 4MB of physical address space. It should not be needed
    ; anymore.
    mov dword [BootPageDirectory], 0
    invlpg [0]

    ; NOTE: From now on, paging should be enabled. The first 4MB of physical address space is
    ; mapped starting at KERNEL_VIRTUAL_BASE. Everything is linked to this address, so no more
    ; position-independent code or funny business with virtual-to-physical address translation
    ; should be necessary. We now have a higher-half kernel.
    mov esp, stack+STACKSIZE           ; set up the stack
    push eax                           ; pass Multiboot magic number

    ; pass Multiboot info structure -- WARNING: This is a physical address and may not be
    ; in the first 4MB!
    push ebx

    call  k_main                 ; call kernel proper
    hlt                          ; halt machine should kernel return


section .bss
align 32
stack:
    resb STACKSIZE      ; reserve 16k stack on a uint64_t boundary
```

Comment: Es para la compilacion de un sistema operativo, no?

Comment: Algo que te recomendaria es que te hagas a un compilador cruzado, asi sera mas facil compilar en cualquier maquina

Comment: He escrito una respuesta para tu inconveniente, espero te sirva, cualquier cosa, puedes escribir en los comentarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La solución, para controlar de una manera mas sencilla la compilación de muchos archivos, consiste en crear un archivo Makefile.

He aquí uno que he creado para tu caso:

```
# Compilador C
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -m32 -ffreestanding

# Ensamblador
AS=nasm
ASFLAGS=-f elf32

# Archivos
ARCHIVOS=kernel.o \
     kernelutils.o \
     loader.o

all: $(ARCHIVOS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o kernel -T linker.ld $(ARCHIVOS)

clean:
    rm -f $(ARCHIVOS)

# Regla: archivos .c
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CLIBS) -c $< -o $@

# Regla: archivos .asm
%.o: %.asm
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Basta guardar dicho texto en un archivo llamado `Makefile`, y dejarlo en el directorio donde se encuentra tu código.

Y ejecutar.

> make all

---

### Explicación

Voy a explicar sección a sección, para que tu entiendas de una manera mas clarar el porque de este archivo.

#### Encabezado

Aquí definimos los compiladores que vamos a usar para nuestro código, cabe aclarar que estas se declaran y se usan como variables de shell, suele ser un formato estandar.

```
# Compilador C
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -m32 -ffreestanding

# Ensamblador
AS=nasm
ASFLAGS=-f elf32
```

Nota: Usamos los parametros `-Wall` para que muestre las advertencias y posibles errores. Espero que conozcas el porque de los otros que ya tenias, como `-ffreestanding` o `-m32`.

#### Archivos

Aquí definimos con que nombres saldran nuestro ficheros objeto, lo que en alguna parte de tu pregunta, tu dijiste:

> Siendo kc.o el archivo kernel.c compilado y kasm.o el archivo loader.asm compilado, ambos compilados siguiendo los siguientes comandos:

Aca estamos definiendo nuevos nombres de archivos, y es facil de aprender los nuevos nombres, ya que el nombre sera el mismo nombre de fichero, con la extension `.o`.

Es decir, *kernel.c -> kernel.o*, *loader.asm -> loader.o*, Etc. Asi sera mas facil identificarlos en el directorio.

```
# Archivos
ARCHIVOS=kernel.o \
         kernelutils.o \
         loader.o
```

Guardando todos estos nombres dentro de una sola variable llamada `ARCHIVOS`.

#### all y clean?

Las dos siguientes reglas, son quiza las siempre requeridas en cualquier archivo Makefile.

```
all: $(ARCHIVOS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o kernel -T linker.ld $(ARCHIVOS)

clean:
    rm -f $(ARCHIVOS)
```

Habiamos previamente hablado de la variable `ARCHIVOS`, la usaremos aca, para construir nuestro programa usando la regla `all` y la usaremos para limpiar nuestro directorio con la regla `clean`.

La regla `all`, hara algo como lo siguiente:

```
gcc -Wall -m32 -ffreestanding -o kernel -T linker.ld kernel.o kernelutils.o loader.o
```

Mientras que la regla clean se encargara de ejecutar lo siguiente:

```
rm -f kernel.o kernelutils.o loader.o
```

Simplemente limpiara los archivos objeto generados durante el proceso de compilacion.

#### Reglas de archivos

Encontramos al final este par de bloques.

```
# Regla: archivos .c
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CLIBS) -c $< -o $@

# Regla: archivos .asm
%.o: %.asm
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Para resumirlo de una manera simple, lo que cada uno de ellos hace es, que al pedir la compilacion de un archivo de extension .c lo compile y su resultado sea el mismo archivo con extension .o. Asi tambien funciona para los archivos de tipo .asm, los compila y retorna el mismo archivos terminando en .o. Solo hacen eso.

### Pero, despues de todo, como funciona?

Te lo resumire en palabras mas claras.

- Tenemos una lista de archivos objetos a generar *(Variable: `ARCHIVOS`)*
- Compilamos cada uno de los archivos respectivos.
- Cuando todos los archivos esten compilados, los enlazamos como un solo ejecutable llamado kernel.

### Nota

Actualmente el codigo esta arrojando ciertas advertencias cuando se esta compilando.

```
nasm -f elf32 loader.asm -o loader.o
```

Resultado

> loader.asm:48: warning: symbol `loader': GLOBAL directive after symbol definition is an experimental feature

Falta hacer una revision de los posibles errores que puedas tener en el codigo antes de hacer el enlazado de los objetos.

Comment: Gracias, todo a ido genial.